# Can't Post to Database [Eloquent]

Tags: php, laravel

i try to chang Method POST > PUT > POST but... can't post anything to my database

another page can create but this not
i try to chang Method POST > PUT > POST but... can't post anything to my database

another page can create but this not

this Route for Post

```php
Route::get('event/{id}/scan', 'scanController@scan')->middleware('auth', 'role:admin');
Route::post('event/{id}/scan', 'scanController@store')->middleware('auth', 'role:admin');
```

this my blade.php

```php
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/event/' . $event->id) .'/scan/'}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ method_field('POST') }}
       {{ csrf_field() }}

 @include ('event.formscan', ['formMode' => 'create']
```

Fromscan.blade.php

```php
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('student_join') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="student_join" class="control-label">{{ 'รหัสนักศึกษา' }}</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="student_join" type="number" id="student_join" value="" >
    {!! $errors->first('student_join', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('event_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="event_id" class="control-label">{{ 'รหัสกิจกรรม' }}</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="event_id" type="number" id="event_id" value="{{ $event->id }}" disabled="">
    {!! $errors->first('event_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ $formMode === 'edit' ? 'ยืนยัน' : 'Create' }}">
</div>
```

Controller
i use $event = event::findOrFail($id); for $id for save to database

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\event;
use App\scan;
use App\booking;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class scanController extends Controller
{
    public function scan($id)
    {
        $event = event::findOrFail($id);
        $scan = scan::all();
        return view('event.scan', compact('event'));
        return redirect('event.scan');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        $item = $request->all();
    }
}
```

Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class scan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'scan';
    protected $primaryKey = 'student_id';
    protected $fillable = ['event_id','name'];
}
```

Comment: In your `store` method, you don't do anything. `$item = $request->all();` just gets the post data, but you don't create a model from it.

Comment: Yes, and your url isn't formed correctly on your blade.  Keep the string inside the method:  `{{ url('/event/' . $event->id) .'/scan/'}}`  - Put the whole thing inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action should be like this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('event/' . $event->id .'/scan') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

or better use a named route

```
Route::post('event/{id}/scan', 'scanController@store')->middleware('auth', 'role:admin')->name('scan.store);
```

then the form action

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('scan.store',$event->id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And finally the controller

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
        //do whatever you want to do 
    }
```